# PHP $_Post a form field from HTML form to PHP through JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, post

Sounds crazy I know, but here is whats going down.  I have a drag and drop file uploader that uses javascript for the drag and drop and sends the files to an upload script in php to save the file to the server. This all works great.  Here is the catch.

I added a form code below

```
<form> 
Customer Name:<input type="text" name="FilesDir" value=""/>
<!--Destination url--><input id="url" input type="hidden" value="upload.php"/>
</form>
```

to set a name to create a directory and then used javascript to pass the value to php

```
var createDirectory = document.getElementById('FilesDir');

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('myfile', file);

formDataDir = new FormData(createDirectory);

xhr.send(formData);

xhr.send(formDataDir);
```

PHP to make the directory as follows

```
$Dir = $_POST["FilesDir"];
if (!is_dir($Dir)) {
mkdir($Dir);
}
```

When I test it doesn't see the posted value, see error below

```
Notice: Undefined index: FilesDir in C:\wamp\www\php_sandbox\Manual_QR\upload.php on    line 3
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0009  261296  {main}( )   ..\upload.php:0

Warning: mkdir(): Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\php_sandbox\Manual_QR\upload.php on line 5
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0009  261296  {main}( )   ..\upload.php:0
2   0.0012  262288  mkdir ( )   ..\upload.php:5
```

HELP Please!

Comment: Er, var_dump($_POST) and post what you're getting from that.

Comment: That's because you have not specified a method for the form. So it will default to GET. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-posting-method)

Comment: I shouldn't have to specify the method, I am using the javascript to post??  I really don't even need the form tags in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url= "page to which you want to post";
var data= "page to which you want to post"; //forexample  'var1='+var1+'&var2='+var2


jQuery.ajax({  
      type: "POST", 
      url: url, 
      data: data,
      complete: function(data){  

  }
 });
```

and use id's for input elements to recognize values in javascript

Comment: I could try this with JQuery, but I was hoping to do it just through my javascript without adding the JQuery Library?