# How to use PHP Variables in an SQL statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables

Before anybody says, I will protect myself against SQL injections, right after I fix this error. I am making an app where news reports are submitted to the database. This page is what removes a report from the database.

What I have tried:
Every possible way of adding brackets to the SQL and speech marks. My ICT teacher and I have looked at this for nearly 2 hours and cannot find a fix. I have also searched Google and Stack Overflow but I cannot find an answer.

Ok, so the correct report_id displays when I echo it. When I put the actual id, eg 5, the report is deleted. But when I put $report_id, nothing is deleted.

Please could somebody tell me what correction I have to make to get this to work ?

Here is the code (EDIT: This is the fixed code. I added the hidden field in the form at the bottom, among a few other small changes (like taking out the extra form tag)):

```
<?php
  require_once('authorize.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Football Central - Remove a Report</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Football Central - Remove a News Report</h2>

<?php
  require_once('img_details_reports.php');
  require_once('connect_db_reports.php');

   //Assign variables from admin_reports.php using $_GET
   $report_id = $_GET['id'];

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     if ($_POST['confirm'] == 'Yes') {

      $report_id = $_POST['id'];
      // Delete the image file from the server
      @unlink(IMAGE_UPLOADPATH . $image);

      // Connect to the database
      $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
      or die("Unable to connect to the database."); 

      // Delete the score data from the database
      $query = "DELETE FROM news_reports WHERE report_id = '".$report_id."' LIMIT 1" 
      or die("mysql_query failed - Error: " . mysqli_error());

      mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("mysql_query failed - Error: " . mysqli_error());
      mysqli_close($dbc);
     }
    }         

    //Display form to confirm delete
    echo '<p>Are you sure you want to delete the news report?</p>';
    echo '<form method="post" action="removereport.php">';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="confirm" value="Yes" /> Yes ';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="confirm" value="No" checked="checked" /> No <br />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $report_id . '" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />';
    echo '</form>';

    echo '<p><a href="admin_reports.php">&lt;&lt; Back to admin reports page</a></p>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for pre-empting boring SQL injection sermon

Comment: How do you send the `id` variable?

Comment: I presume your gets var, submit, confirm and id exists, right....try making an echo of every one of them at the begin of your php script

Comment: Whenever I send queries to MYSQL I end them with a semi-colon. Not sure if that's necessary. Give it a go? Also, what is the error code? What do you see if you print `$query`?

Comment: wait... what are you doing here? A form in a form?!

Comment: Thank you SAVAFA you fixed it :D I needed to add it hidden in the form. Sorry I don't know why I have a nested form, stupid mistake :)

Comment: @lukecolli98, did I solve it or someone else (based on your selected answer, which previously was mine)? ;)

Comment: Oh sorry, I hadn't seen my stack for a few days and there were so many answers :D I changed your answer to the solve thing. I have just updated the code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the `form` with `post` method and retrieving it with `get`. That can be the source of the problem.

Also you are not sending the `id` parameter so, there won't be any value for `$_get[id]` nor `$_post[id]`

Comment: but I don't see any input name="id" there?

Comment: The default form method is GET ([see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-posting-method)), but your point about the lack of an `id` id valid.

Comment: you are right about the default, but he is setting the method as `post` already

Comment: Ohhh. He has a nested form. There is a form header two lines before without a `method=`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I added the input id into the form and it works great !

Comment: @lukecolli98, update your codes in the initial so that I can take a look at it.

Comment: @lukecolli98, why do you have both of these lines: `$report_id = $_GET['id'];` and `$report_id = $_POST['id'];`, and what is the problem after all the modifications?

Comment: @SAVAFA, That's just a mistake. The only problem now is that everyone here said I should change everything to POST instead of GET, but when I do this the ID is not retrieved ?

Comment: How do you know that the `id` is not retrieved by `$_POST['id']`? Your online example just works fine and the row is removed.

Answer (score 3):

Your are mixing two statements. Just try below.

```
  // Delete the score data from the database
  $query = "DELETE FROM news_reports WHERE report_id = ".$report_id;  
  mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("mysql_query failed - Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer. the `die` statement is misplaced

Comment: @Matanya That's right, but a string should evaluate to boolean true, so this won't cause the problem...

Comment: Is it correct for sending the database link, see it in here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @bwoebi, You are right. lcolli98, can you `var_dump($query)` and show us the output?

Comment: Hi, everything is fixed after I added the ID into the form ! When I use POST, the ID is not retrieved, only with GET. Do you know why this is ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to wrap the ID in single-quotes, if the ID is a number.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM news_reports WHERE report_id = '".$report_id."' LIMIT 1"
```

But that's not the problem.  You did not include the ID in your confirmation request, or allow for retrieving the value from a session variable.  Add a hidden input box with the id, in your "Display form to confirm delete" section.

(And have a different code branch for confirmation!  And a test for an invalid ID!  And move this to POST, at the very least!)

Comment: Hi thanks for that ! When I use POST, the ID is not retrieved, only with GET. Do you know why this is ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got

```
$query = "..." or die(...);
```

Why?

Also, you've got two form opening tags -- it's not valid to nest forms.

I'm going to assume that the `id` variable comes in from some source other than the form because there's no form element that submits it.

Finally, make sure to specify `get` or `post` in your form. I'd recommend using `post`, and then change `$_GET["submit"]` and `$_GET["confirm"]` to `$_POST["submit"]` and `$_POST["confirm"]`.

Comment: Hi, the or die was to see if I could get the exact problem :) When I use POST, the ID is not retrieved, only with GET. Do you know why this is ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check following things in your code.

- Where is your ID element in the form
- You have put POST method in form but retrieving data from **$_GET**, you should change it to **$_POST**.
- Put mysqli_error after mysqli_query  statement.

  ```
  $query = "DELETE FROM news_reports WHERE report_id = ".$report_id;

  mysqli_query($dbc, $query);  or die("mysql_query failed - Error: " . mysqli_error());
  ```

Then check the error from mysql if it does not work.

Hope, it will help you in solving your issue.

Comment: Hi, I added the ID into the form and it works great ! When I use POST, the ID is not retrieved, only with GET. Do you know why this is ?