# My query doesn't work when updating database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a form like the following:

```
<form action="campionat.php?competitii='.$idcompetitie.'">
    <input type="submit" name="upgrade" value="inainte" />
</form>
```

On `campionat.php`:

```
    if($_POST['upgrade']=="inainte")
    {    
        $lvlupstadion   = $levelstadio+1;
        $cost               = 10000000*$lvlupstadion;
        $bugetnou       = $buget - $cost;

        $q = mysql_query("UPDATE echipa SET levelstadion='".$lvlupstadion."' , buget='".$bugetnou."' WHERE (`echipa`='".$echipa."') AND (`user`='".$id."') AND (`competitie`='".$competitie."')") ;
        if (!$q)
        {
            echo  mysql_error($q);
        }
        echo $lvlupstadion.$bugetnou.$echipa.$id.$competitie;
    }
```

Why my database does not change and my script doesn't alert me about errors?

Comment: because your $_POST['upgrade'] is not getting value from form action

Comment: add like this `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error())` to track the errors.

Comment: mysql_* is deprected, use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 2):

The default method of a `<form>` tag is GET.

Since your form has no method specified, it'll send a get. In which case `$_POST['upgrade']` is not available.

If you change

```
<form action="campionat.php?competitii='.$idcompetitie.'">
    <input type="submit" name="upgrade" value="inainte" />
</form>
```

to

```
<form method="post" action="campionat.php?competitii='.$idcompetitie.'">
    <input type="submit" name="upgrade" value="inainte" />
</form>
```

it should work.

Please refer to this question: [What is the default form HTTP method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-posting-method)

Answer (score 1):

Your form does not have a `method`, therefore it will default to `GET`. This is a problem because you are trying to access `$_POST['upgrade']` which will never be set.

Set the method to `post`.

```
<form method="post" ... >
```

From [W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3):

> **method**
>
> Possible (case-insensitive) values are "get" (the default) and "post"

Comment: sorry for my fault that is the form <form action="http://mmo-arena.ro/fifa/echipa.php?idcompetitie='.$idcompetitie.'" method="POST">
     <input type="submit" name="upgradestadion" value="Inainte" />
     </form>

Answer (score 1):

Your form is missing things . You have to choose between $_GET and $_POST. + What are you doing with $q?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
(`user`='".$id."')
```

Is an ID (int) you don't need simple quote. It might help you

Comment: -1 won't make any difference (please do not submit guesses as answers)

Comment: @AD7six suggestion will be good enough and had an answer either edit it or post it...

Comment: When posted it, there was no anwser yet, so please stop trolling. I just try to help, and you'r just borring me.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in hidden field and then send it to another page

```
<form action="campionat.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="competitii" value="<?php echo $idcompetitie; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="upgrade" value="inainte" />
</form>
```

your redirection is not sending the value from form post method.

Comment: Moving the id from the url (form action) to a hidden field does not address the original error (which is corrected by this answer, but not mentioned).