# What does form action="/scripts" mean?

Tags: html, http

I'm looking at the source code for bing.com for the file that processes the search upon submittance.

The search bar form for bing.com is like so:

```
<form action="/search" class="sw_box" id="sb_form" onsubmit="return si_T('&amp;ID=FD,6.1');">
```

*I have 2 questions:*

*(i) What method is this form sent by? Where is the method="GET" or method "POST"?*

*(ii) Where is the form data sent to? What does "/search" mean, and does it imply bing.com/search.php or asp?*

Comment: Your question says different, your code shows different

Comment: /search is the url the form will submit to. The file extension is not supplied in this example. URL rewriting will determine that.

Comment: Do you really expect MS to use PHP?ASP maybe?

Answer (score 2):

> What method is this form sent by? Where is the method="GET" or method "POST"?

[The invalid value default for these attributes is the GET state. The missing value default for the method attribute is also the GET state.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method)

> Where is the form data sent to?  What does "/search" mean?

It is a relative URI starting with a `/` so, assuming there is no `<base>` element, `$FOO/search` where `$FOO` is the current scheme and hostname.

> and does it imply bing.com/search.php or asp?

No.

There might be a `search.php` file or a `search.asp` file, and the server might map `/search` onto one of them, but that would be internal to the server. It is of no concern to the browser and there is no way to tell what is happening inside the server without access to it through some mechanism other than HTTP.

It could be handled by something else entirely, I run a site where `/tag/` (and everything else that isn't a static file) is mapped on to `/home/sitename-web/src/AppName/script/appname_fastcgi.pl/`. That program then [determines the response to send based on the URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ETHER/Catalyst-Manual-5.9007/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Action-Types).

Answer (score 0):

1. The [default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2314441/3269863) is GET, when the method attribute is omitted
2. /search means /search. This can be /search/index.html or /search/index.php or whatever. We don't know. This depends on the server configuration and possible a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

1) The [default method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2314441/794234) of a form is GET

2) `/search` probably does not refer to a physical file on disk (like search.asp or search.php). Instead, when the server receives a request for `/search`, it uses [URL routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) to choose what to do with the request (in this case execute a search and show results).