# MVC + T4MVC - How to pass a url action to form? Or an alternative method to generate action/id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, t4mvc

I'm looping through a model and iterating through data. I want to add a button on each item that generates an action/id.

As I cannot add a url to a button , I've decided to use a form with the following:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("ItemDetail", new { itemId = @quote.Item.ItemID})">
    <button class="btn-bg btn-sm btn-inverse btn-fix-width" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-th-list fa-fw pull-right"></i>View RFQ
    </button>
</form>
```

I opted for a button instead of input type to inset font-awesome icons.

However, I get **/Quote/ItemDetail?** as opposed to **/Quote/ItemDetail?itemId=123**

I'm using T4MVC

Controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult ItemDetail(int ItemID)
{
    return View();
}
```

RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: try to use @Url.Action("ACTION", "CONTROLLER", new { itemId = @quote.Item.ItemID}) or @Url.Action("ACTION", "CONTROLLER", null, new { itemId = @quote.Item.ItemID})

Comment: Can you put the controller code here?

Comment: @Zaphod forgot to mention I'm using T4MVC

Comment: @renefc3 As requested. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With T4MVC, something like this should work:

```
<form action="@Url.Action(MVC.Quote.ItemDetail(quote.Item.ItemID))">
```

...Note that this is assuming the `ItemDetail` action is on your `QuoteController`. If the controller name is different, change `Quote` to whatever the name of your controller is.

You could also go more with @Zaphod's comment and do something like this:

```
<form action="@Url.Action(MVC.Quote.ActionNames.ItemDetail, MVC.Quote.Name,
    new { itemId = @quote.Item.ItemID})">
```

...at least here T4MVC gets rid of your magic strings, even if you are still using MVC's out of the box `Url.Action` overload.

You should also name your action method arguments using `camelCase`, not `PascalCase`:

```
public virtual ActionResult ItemDetail(int itemId) // instead of ItemID
{
    return View();
}
```

...though I don't think that should cause any issues.

**Update**

Try this maybe?

```
<form method="GET" action="@Url.Action(MVC.Quote.ItemDetail(quote.Item.ItemID))">
```

or this:

```
<form method="GET" action="@Url.Action(MVC.Quote.ActionNames.ItemDetail, MVC.Quote.Name)">
    <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="@quote.Item.ItemID" />
    <button class="btn-bg btn-sm btn-inverse btn-fix-width" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-th-list fa-fw pull-right"></i>View RFQ
    </button>
</form>
```

**Another update:**

You should also be able to do this instead, and then use CSS to make your link look like a button:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Quote.ItemDetail(quote.Item.ItemID))">
    <i class="fa fa-th-list fa-fw pull-right"></i>View RFQ
</a>
```

IMHO, this is what you really *should* do, since you're only sending one parameter.

Comment: Hey thanks, although I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: EDIT: It does work when I check inside chrome's developer tools! However, when I click the button, I get: Quote/ItemDetail? in the url bar

Comment: @DarkShadowAY - so MVC is rendering the correct href attribute, but when you click it, the querystring parameter is being stripped from the URL? I'm not sure what you mean by "it works in chrome dev tools". If this is the case, check fiddler to see what is going on with the requests (maybe MVC is redirecting it for some reason).

Comment: Yes, when I go to inspect the form action using web developer, it generates: /Quote/ItemDetail?itemId=4084. However, when I click on the button, I get: http://locahost:3435/Quote/ItemDetail? - It doesn't seem to be picking up the action

Comment: @DarkShadowAY your routes look good. Use Fiddler to inspect the HTTP requests and responses that take place after you click on the link. When you hover over the link, I assume you see the correct URL in the bottom of the page? If so, something else is going on when the server receives the request. Fiddler should help you figure it out.

Comment: When I hover over the form, nothing appears. The path is  /Quote/ItemDetail?itemId=4084 instead of localhost/Quote/ItemDetail?itemId=4084 thanks

Comment: I added <form action="@Url.Action(MVC.Quote.ItemDetail(quote.Item.ItemID), Request.Url.Scheme)"> which gives the full url http://localhost/Quote/ItemDetail?itemId=4084 but click changes it. So odd. I'm marking as resolved as you answered my initial question but would appreciate further help. Cheers. I've also tried fidder, pretty much the same info it directs to http://localhost/Quote/ItemDetail?

Comment: @DarkShadowAY like I said twice before, download Fiddler and use it to inspect the raw HTTP traffic.

Comment: Edited prev comment - I've tried fiddler and it's GET request is http://localhost/Quote/ItemDetail?

Comment: @DarkShadowAY that is messed up. Are you sure that is the **only** request that comes after you click the link? And do you see the same behavior in Firefox and Internet Explorer?

Comment: I have indeed. It's certainly got something to do with the way the form is handled. I just put the same into a url href and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @DarkShadowAY I updated my answer. See if adding a `method="get"` attribute to your form element helps.

Comment: I completely missed that. It was post, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @DarkShadowAY good you had me going crazy. GET is the default method, so when you omit it, it should do GET by default. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2314441/304832 In the future, post all of the relevant code.