# Laravel resource route to root

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Is it possible to set a resource route to root?

Like:

```
Route::resource('/', 'HomeController');
```

So I could use these urls:

```
/
/create
/214
/214/edit
```

I've tried, **create**, **index** works, route('store') recognized, but doesn't call store the function and redirects to home.

Comment: How did you hit the store method?  Keep in mind that it's a post route and won't work if you try to hit it with your browser.

Comment: Created a form, and using route('store'). Laravel recognize it's a valid route, so it creates an url to /.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need help with this one, since it's been more than a year. Try putting this in your blade file.

```
<form action="{{ route('store') }}" method="POST">
```

I've had a similar problem with my code. My original form had this, at the very beginning (using default documentation code here):

```
<form action="{{ route('photo.store') }}>
```

which, after trying it out, didn't work as I would expect - nothing was being stored. After making sure that the rest of the code was OK, one of my colleagues suggested that I type in the method type, since [the default method is GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method), and you need the POST method for [storing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is `Route::resource('/', 'HomeController');`.