# Bootstrap and Flask: How to receive a POST?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm designing a small web calculator using Bootstrap and Flask. However I'm close finished, here is my code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('finish.html',
                               number1=request.form['number1'],
                               number2=request.form['number2'],
                               finish=(request.form['number1'] * request.form['number2']))
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

And here is a part of `index.html`:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number1" placeholder="Number1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number2" placeholder="Number2">
    </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So I wish receive a POST, and return the result. But when I trying to run my program, enter these two number and submit them. The program didn't receive a POST, here is the log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Sep/2015 22:20:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Sep/2015 22:20:25] "GET /dist/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Sep/2015 22:20:25] "GET /assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Sep/2015 22:20:29] "GET /?number1=12&number2=32 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

So the program received something like `GET /?number1=12&number2=32`, not a post. And the web page is still at `/`. How do I change this to POST or use `/?number1=12&number2=32`？

Comment: Maybe by using `<form method="POST">` in html helps.

Comment: @jlnabais Let me try that :)

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method).

Comment: @jlnabais Well, the output is the same. I think that because bootstrap. If I don't use it the program will work good.

Comment: When you fixed the `method="POST"` issue - did you refresh the page in your browser (or wherever you're testing)?  Use Ctrl-Refresh to ensure all caches are clear etc and then re-test with that fixed.

Comment: @JRichardSnape Hmm...When I click the button, the page will auto refresh. And the numbers that I entered will be clear. And the link will be change to `/?number1=12&number2=22`, but the web page is still `/`(only change the like, didn't change the page and didn't raise a 404 error).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your form so that it posts the data (you also have to add some bootstrap info) :

```
<form method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
```

Also change your button to an input :

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Well, the output is the same. I think that because bootstrap. If I don't use it the program will work good.

Comment: Bootstrap isn't supposed to change how your html forms act.

Comment: Well, the problem is still there.

Comment: When I press the button, the link will change to `http://0.0.0.0:5000/?number1=123&number2=123`. And then nothing will happen. The log show that received some GET like I wrote in my question.

Comment: I've edited my answer. you have to add `role='form'`

Comment: Nothing changed. Maybe I should learn what does `GET /?number1=12&number2=32` mean?

Comment: All right I don't know why doesn't this work before, but now this can work so good. However Thanks :)