# Links don't work on localhost

Tags: php, localhost

I'm using `localhost` and I want to go from `index.php` to `register.php` using a simple hyperlink. They are in the same folder. I can access `register.php` if I manually type it in the address bar.

I tried:

```
<button name="register"><a href="register.php">Register</a></button>

<button name="register"><a href="http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName/register.php">Register</a></button>

<button name="register"><a href="MyProjectName/register.php">Register</a></button>
```

**Solution:**

```
<form action="register.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: Well, what URL are you using for the index.php and what URL are you manually entering for register.php that work? And define what you mean by don't work.

Comment: Try to use <a href="/register.php">

Comment: no closing `</a>` tag or text for it. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html - This is **HTML 101** stuff.

Comment: @JonStirling - the second URL from my example. The files are both in the same directory on my disk.

Comment: why are you using button and href??

Comment: why are you doing so many edits? and what does your solution have to do with the hrefs?

Comment: @Fred-ii- - yeah, that was the problem. Thanks for the question!

Comment: had you posted what you really wanted to do, I'd of posted an answer within the first 15 seconds. When things are unclear, I ask questions ;-)

Comment: ...and you're welcome ;-)

Comment: Btw, you inversed the `button/a` where that should have read as `a/button`, as shown in my answer below. @Bacchus which is one reason why it didn't work. The question should be marked as solved, otherwise it will remain in the unanswered category. Otherwise, others may be tempted to post more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your many (incremental) edits, I have decided to post the following.

Now knowing what you really wanted to do here from the get go...

FYI: Buttons only work when set inside `<form></form>` tags, or when you're using JS/Ajax.

You've made quite a few edits and should have posted your intention from the start.

What you could have done was

`<a href="file.php"><button>Text</button></a>` which works.

and not the other way around `<button><a href="file.php">Text</a></button>` (won't work).

Or others such as:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Button</a> (bootstrap style)
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Input Button">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit Button">
```

or a standard hyperlink that leads to another page, which was your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33756366/1 where you had the missing `</a>` closing tags.

- Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html

Sidenote: Forms default to a GET method if omitted.

`<form></form>`

If you want to use a POST method, it needs to be specified.

`<form method="post"></form>`

Consult the following:

- [What is the default form HTTP method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method)
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Answer (score 0):

If the register.php is in the same direction as your index the first relative path ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

simply use `<a href="register.php">Register</a>`
you may have to use css with some class or id to make you a look like a button

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to make this perfect is define your host like

```
define('HOST_URL', 'http://localhost');
```

and now you just ned to add this with your page link like

```
<button name="register"><a href="<?=HOST_URL?>/register.php">Register</a></button>

<button name="register"><a href="<?=HOST_URL?>/MyProjectName/register.php">Register</a></button>

<button name="register"><a href="<?=HOST_URL?>/MyProjectName/register.php">Register</a></button>
```

Now from one place you can change. Not to worry for change manually and searching them. Hope this helps