# Contact form having trouble to access a php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to configure my 'send message/submit' button so that when clicked it accesses a php file in the local directory and executes the code to email the corresponding data.

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aclz3.png)

The HTML code shows the following:

```
   <section class="contact-us">
    <div class="form-wrapper">
        <div class="contact-form">

            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <input id="Field12" name="Field12" placeholder="Full Name" required="" tabindex="1" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline-groups">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <input id="Field3" maxlength="255" name="Field3" placeholder="Email" required="" spellcheck="false" tabindex="2" type="email" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <input id="Field4" maxlength="255" name="Field4" placeholder="Phone number (optional)" tabindex="3" type="tel" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <textarea cols="50" id="Field5" name="Field5" placeholder="Let us know what we can do for you!" spellcheck="true" tabindex="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input id="idstamp" name="idstamp" type="hidden" value="r885sYVzp1O8HO4V4MdnZvkis7E3NZIfZ8CtHRCtCdY">
                    <button class="button" action="send_form_email.php" type="submit">Send message</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

The PHP code shows the following:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['email'])) { 

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "matty65622@hotmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Greenmount Engineering | Customer Enquiry";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['tel']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $name = $_POST['name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['tel']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The name you entered does not seem to be valid.<br />';

  }


  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }


    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

I am not sure if this code will work 100% yet as I have not tried it, but as you can see the attempt to link the HTML button to the php script only refreshes the page when sent, but when I check my email nothing comes through. 
`<button class="button" action="send_form_email.php"`

Comment: `<form method="post" action="send_form_email.php">` && `<button type="submit">Send</button>`.

Comment: When the button is clicked, it takes me to a new webpage with the php code, it doesnt seem to be executing/emailing this data to the targeted email? Can you review my php and tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: seeing the comments below, am guessing that you're trying to run this from your own computer without a webserver installed or PHP, or running as `c:///file.xxx` instead of `http://localhost/file.xxx` @Revo am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace one line of code.

Always use action in form tag so move the `action="send_form_email.php"` in `<form method="post">` tag and your code will run.

Comment: You forgot to mention the `method` attribute that has to be set to `post`. It will send the form with `get` otherwise.

Comment: [No, forms are sent with `get` method by default.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2314441/2788131)

Comment: Thanks for pointing i'll edit. Thanks

Comment: When the button is clicked, it takes me to a new webpage with the php code, it doesnt seem to be executing/emailing this data to the targeted email? Can you review my php and tell me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A few adjustments need to be done to your code:

1. Add `method="post"` attribute to your `<form>` tag (so the method used is not `get`).
2. Add `action="send_form_email.php"` attribute to your `<form>` tag (so your form redirects to your script).
3. Add `name="submit"` to your `<button>` tag (so the expression `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` in `send_form_email.php` evaluates to `true` and the code block gets executed).
4. Change `name` attributes of your `<input>`s according to your `$_POST['...']` (so PHP recognizes the input values).

And you should be good to go.

Comment: name="submit" or type="submit"  ?? Also, in: <form method="post" action="send_form_email.php"> && <button type="submit">Send</button>

Comment: The && are showing as text, not as actual functioning code

Comment: Both `name` and `type` are required in your `<button>` tag here. The `&&` is just here to let you know to make **both** adjustments.

Comment: It's not working :/ My php code is wrong but I have updated it, please go through it and help me fix why its continuing to open the code in a browser and not send to my target email?

Comment: @Revo because, you don't have a webserver/PHP/mail installed or you're accessing as `c:///file.xxx` instead of `http://localhost/file.xxx`. Pretty straightforward here.

Comment: So you are saying, my php script (**send_form_email.php**), in the: `<form method="post" action="**http://localhost/send_form_email.php**">` it should be like this? rather than a direct link to my script from my computer? And yes I do not have a webserver/php/mail installed..? I am just trying to make it so that this code sends the data to the email targeted but it doesnt actually leave the page that im at (**Contact Us**)

Comment: @Revo: One needs to have implemented a working web server for PHP to be executed (or use CLI).