# JQuery form submit into database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I want to make a simple CRUD using modal bootstrap and Jquery submit button and framework that i use is laravel 5.2, below is my controller, modal, jquery and routes, the problem is when i click save changes nothing happen, is there anything im doing wrong?

> **MODAL**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Barang</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="addModal">
                <form id="tambahform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" id="client-nama" name="clientName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn-add btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var check1=0;
    $('#tambahform').submit(function(e){
    if (check1==0){
        $("#addModal").animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    }else{
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url:'form/insert',
            data:formData,
            type:'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data){
                $("#addModal").hide();
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
    });
```

> **Controller**

```
public function insert(){
    $nama = Input::get('nama');
    $this->nama = Input::get('clientName');
    $query = DB::table('profile')->insert(array('nama'=>$nama));  

}
```

> **ROUTES**

```
Route::get('form/insert', 'FormController@insert');
```

Comment: This should be $nama = Input::get('nama'); this $nama = Input::get('clientName');

Comment: look at my controller again, someting like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the method you will be using to submit the `form` as. There is no `method` mentioned so it is submitting its [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method), `GET`.

so you `form` tag should look like this:

```
<form method="POST" id="tambahform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

In the `url`, you need to give it a full path or else it will give a `404 not found` error. Take a look at this code:

```
e.preventDefault();
var formData = $(tambahform).serialize(); //<--use Serialize
 $.ajax({
     url:'form/insert.php', //<--add full path including the files extension here
     data:formData,
     type:'POST',
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     success:function(data){
            $("#addModal").hide();
            window.location.reload(true);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
Route::get('form/insert', 'FormController@insert');
```

use this

```
Route::post('form/insert', 'FormController@insert');
```

Comment: still nothing happen, when i click submit button nothing happen, am i doing wrong in my controller or my script?

Comment: you should check the error in console using firebug .

Comment: well i already read how to use it, but still don't know how to use it

Comment: in firebug there is console part, just submit the form , after submission if it works then you will  get the post request  in console.