# Adding records to a database using a html form

Tags: php, sql

Having trouble populating my database usning a html form. Once i run the code the webpage outputs "Completed successfully" but the record does not display. It seems like its entering null values for each of the fields because when i try to enter another record, i'm getting this error "connected successfully Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'" How can i solve this?

```
<form action="addplayer.php"method "post"/>

     <p> id: <input type="text" name="playerid"/></p>
     <p> Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></p>
     <p> Age: <input type="text" name="age"/></p>
     <p> Position: <input type="text" name="position"/></p>
     <p> Nationality: <input type="text" name="nationality"/></p>
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>


     ?php
require 'connection.php';


$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'playerid');
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age');
$position = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'position');
$nationality = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nationality');

$_id = mysql_real_escape_string( $id );
$_name = mysql_real_escape_string( $name );
$_age = mysql_real_escape_string( $age );
$_position = mysql_real_escape_string( $position );
$_nationality = mysql_real_escape_string( $nationality );
$sql = "INSERT INTO players ( playerid, name, age, position, nationality ) 
         VALUES ( '$_id', '$_name', '$_age', '$_position', '$_nationality' )";

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Create one column name `id` `Auto increment` set it's `PRIMARY` key.

Comment: does your form tag really have `method "post"` instead of `method="post"`, or is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: If the form method is not defined, it [defaults to GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method), so the POST values will all be empty.

Comment: The form end tag (</form>) is missing

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to add id to the input:

```
<p> id: <input type="text" name="playerid" id="playerid"/></p>
```

collect the data like this:

```
$playerID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['playerid'])

$sql = "INSERT INTO players
        SET
        playerID = '".$playerID."',
        ........";
```

Comment: an `id` attribute is not required for the form to pass data from an input; the `name` attribute is sufficient.