# $_POST doesn't work with my form

Tags: php

Now i made a simple form with 2 input one for name and one for button
i want in php file echo name input

```
<form action="del.php">                                     
<input type="text"  name="name" />
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="button"/>
</form>
```

> in del.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
echo "".$_POST['name']."";
```

giving me white screen when every time
i want to echo any thing that typed in this input

Comment: Why are you using type like this `"text" "` should it not be `type="text"` only?

Comment: @Jer because my original code have placeholder="" when i delete extra things to be simple code i didn't see it sorry

Comment: <form method="post" action="del.php">, your missing the method on your form

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `method` attribute in your form.

```
<form action="del.php" method="POST">                                     
    <input type="text"  name="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="button"/>
</form>
```

---

> The method attribute specifies how to send form-data (the form-data is sent to the page specified in the action attribute).
>
> The form-data can be sent as URL variables (with **method="get"**) or as HTTP post transaction (with **method="post"**).

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: @rekobeko It's cool when you accept an answer as correct. It means a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

the [default method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method) when a form is submitted is `GET`, you need to specify the `POST` method (method="post") in your `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="del.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is not POSTing its GETing (see the url params which will be set `example.com?name=`) this is because you not set the from method for POST:

```
<form action="del.php" method="post">                                     
    <input type="text"  name="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="button"/>
</form>
```

And within your PHP you should check its post and check that the values are set:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;

    // set your session - not sure you need this :/
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;

    // echo out your result but also protect from XSS by using htmlentities
    echo htmlentities($name); 
}
```