# Using JSP in Form action

Tags: html, jsp

I came across a ocwcd question as follows:

```
<form action="sendOrder.jsp"> 
  <input type="text" name="creditCard">
  <input type="text" name="expirationDate"> 
  <input type="submit"/> 
</form>
```

considering the above piece of code question is :
when creating a web form with this HTML which HTTP method is used when sending this request from the browser?

Options were given as below:

A. GET
B. PUT
C. POST 
D. SEND
E. FORM

In my view ans will be C.POST.but answer is given as A.GET

Can anyone provide any explanation to this???or is it a typo error in solution sheet?

Comment: I think it is better to add "method" attribute into form tag to set http request method.

Comment: GET is the default form submission method. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/2314401/1039555.

Comment: qichunren,we all know that,it is an exam question.And question is that whether GET or POST which one will be prefereble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET is the default form submission method. Take a look at stackoverflow.com/q/2314401/1039555.