# GET request in Django

Tags: html, django

I have a doubt. When is a GET request sent. I mean, I have seen a lot of people using if `request.method == 'GET'`, when they render the form for the first time, but when the form is submitted, they do a `POST' request.

While they explicitly mention when defining the form in html that the method will be 'POST', they don't do the same for 'GET' request which is made when an empty form is requested.

How does django know it's a GET request?

And, why is it done so?

Thanks,

Comment: `GET` typically makes *no* changes to the database (and other persistent structures). `POST` typically does. You have other request methods as well like `PUT`, `PATCH`, `OPTION`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @WillemVanOnsem.
Actually, my doubt is, when I click a signup page, it open in front of me an empty page and this was done using a GET request. How does Django get to know it's a GET request when nothing was mentioned explicitly.
And, why it made a GET request? Is this the default behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert but I think Django "knows" this because like all things on the Internet it uses the HTTP protocol. [There are several HTTP methods.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#/Request_methods) If not specified the default method will always be [GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method)

Comment: Thank you @Ovidiu, I just checked by printing the method. The default method is GET and that clears my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Django is based on HTTP responses-requests. HTTP is fully textuall. So Django parses each request and finds in its header information about what kind of request is it. I may be mistaken in details, but as I understand when server receives request - Django creates it's object `request`, which contains all the data from HTTP. And then you decide if you need a specific action on `GET` or `POST` and you check the type of request with `request.method`.
**P.S.** And yes, by default each request is `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

## `GET`

A `GET` is usually used to *retrieve* information. Typically a `GET` function has *no* side-effects (this means that data in the database is *not* changed, that no files in the filesystem are modified, etc.).

Strictly speaking this is not always true, since some webservers log requests (themselves) and thus add an entry to the database that a specific user visited a specific page at a specific timestamp, etc.

A typical `GET` request is *idempotent*. This means that there is no difference between doing a query one time, or multiple times (two times, three times, five times, thousand times).

`GET` queries are therefore typically used to provide static content, as well as pages that contain data about one or more entries, search queries, etc.

## `POST`

`POST` on the other hand typically ships with data (in the `POST` parameters), and usually the idea is that something is done with this data that creates a change in the persistent structures of the webserver. For example creating a new entry in some table, or updating the table with the values that are provided. Since these operations are not always *idempotent*, it can be dangerous if the user *refreshes* the page in the browser (since that could for example create two orders, instead of the single order the user actually wanted to create).

Therefore in Django a `POST` request will typically result in some changes to the database, and a `redirect` as result. This means that the user will typically obtain a new address, and perform a `GET` request on that page (and that `GET` is idempotent, hence it will not construct a new order).

## `PUT`, `PATCH` and `DELETE`

Besides the popular `GET` and `POST`, there are other typical requests a client can make to a webserver. For example `PUT`, `PATCH` and `DELETE`.

### `PUT`

`PUT` is the twin of a `POST` request. The main difference is that the URI it hits, specifies what entry to construct or update. `PUT` is usually an *idempotent* operation.

This means that if we would for example perform a `POST server.com/blog/create` to create a blog, `PUT` will typically look like `PUT server.com/blog/123/`. So we specify the `id` in advance. In case the object does not yet exists, a webserver will typically construct one. In case the entity *already exists*, a new entity will typically be constructed for that URI. So performing the same `PUT` operation twice, should have no effect.

Note that in case of a `PUT` request, typically one should specify *all* fields. The fields that are *not* specified will typically be filled in with *default* values (in case such values exist). We thus do not really "update" the entity: we destroy the old entity and create a new one in case that entity already exists.

### `PATCH`

`PATCH` is a variant of `PUT` that *updates* the entity, instead of creating a new one. The fields that are thus missing in a `PATCH` request, typically remain the same as the values in the "*old*" entity so to speak.

### `DELETE`

Like the name already suggests, if we perform a `DELETE server.com/blog/123/` request, then we will typically remove the corresponding element.

Some servers do *not* immediately remove the corresponding element. You can see it as scheduling the object for deletion, so sometimes the object is later removed. The `DELETE` request, thus typically means that you signal the server to *eventually* remove the entity.