# HTML form that causes a GET request

Tags: html, get

Basic question. If I have a form in my HTML (where in my case someone inputs a date), how can I have my users cause a GET request with the contents of that form instead of a POST.

e.g. form entry (e.g date)... so `20190312`

what I am trying to achieve is such that AFTER the user submits the form.. the user is the lead to page that has

```
GET domain.tld/scriptname.php?variable=20190312
```

and then the system then processes the GET request accordingly.

thank you

Comment: please provide code

Comment: A bit unclear what you are asking here. Do you want users to send the form data to your system first, and then have your system make a GET request to a different domain in the background? Or what exactly is the issue?

Comment: [Form method attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_method_attribute)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette — The method attribute is not needed. `GET` is the default for it.

Comment: You are right @Quentin... I only posted a link so OP could read a bit. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default form HTTP method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe i'm missunderstanding what you are asking.

This can easly be achived using builtin **GET** method in FORM tag

---

```
<body>
    <form id="form" method="GET" action="scriptname.php">
        <input id="date-txt" type="text" name="date">
        <input id="search-btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

While filling up above field ad clicking "Submit" form will be submitted and you can see in your url path/or/page/**scriptname.php?date=INPUT_FIELD_VAL**

for every input in #form with a name, if GET method is used, you'll see a **?name=value** in the url

Comment: nailed it.. i had just assumed that all of the forms were handled via POST... learn something every day.. thank you for taking the time to answer a basic question appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the default behaviour of a form. If you don't want a POST request, then don't use a `method` attribute to set the request type to `POST`.

```
<form action="//domain.tld/scriptname.php">
    <input name="variable" value="20190312">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```