# PHP not displaying errors (turned on) and code is dying at some point

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a simple registration form with PHP, storing the user data in a database after processing the form etc. But the PHP code will not work, but not display any errors either. I have turned on error reporting in the php.ini file and also have included:

1. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
2. `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`
   at the top of all used php files.
   I have a feeling that it has something to do with my MySQLi statements.
   The most likely lines for error are here:

   ```
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

       // Validate username
       if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
           $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
       } else{
           require_once "db_conn.php";
           // Prepare a select statement
           $sql = "SELECT id FROM estiweb_db WHERE username = ?";

           if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
               // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
               mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

               // Set parameters
               $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

               // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
               if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                   // store result
                   mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                   if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                       $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                   } else{
                       $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                   }
               } else{
                   echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
               }
           }

           // Close statement
           mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
       }
   ```

There are a few blocks of code similar to this to validate the other fields in `register.php`.

I have tried already to change the way the code is constructed, different processing order. Also I have tried to change the MySQLi to MySQL (I would prefer not to but it was worth a shot).

I have copied my files into a pastebin, I know I should just use small bits but I am unsure exactly where the problem is originating from. Would appreciate anyone who looks over this and can see anything wrong.

The links are:

- `register.php`:  https://pastebin.com/PwfgCby5
- `validation.php`:  https://pastebin.com/sbr2DEHK
- `db_conn.php`:  https://pastebin.com/j14d8RWw

Comment: hi, where have you looked for PHP logging?

Comment: oops! If i am honest, nowhere -_- let me find it real quick, im using ubuntu and nginx :) i will post back one mo' :)

Comment: Your `<form>` tag  doesn't have any `method` so by [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method) it will take `GET`  method and your `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` will never be true , just add `method="post"` under your `<form>` tag.

Comment: try `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: I checked logs for the site, there are some but older ones, I corrected those yesterday (was an unexpected end of file, an extra ' } '. But after checking the files on the server are the newest, i re-opened the log file after again attempting the fill in the reg form and store to databse.No new errors have shown up in the log file.

Comment: omg @Swati how could i be so stupid....

Comment: will make the correction and report back aha

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /www-data/www.estiweb.co.uk/public_html/phplogin/php/validation.php on line 114
Something went wrong. Please try again later.
Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /www-data/www.estiweb.co.uk/public_html/phplogin/php/validation.php on line 139

Comment: got this new error let me see if i can solve :) thanks for your help so far guys <3

Comment: @JoshuaRead `$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO estiweb_db (username, email, password) VALUES (? ,?, ?)");` This needs TWO parameters, so add `$link` in to your MySQL query as the FIRST parameter.