# Flask template Not rendered, and insertion to the database doesn't happen

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I am making a template that shows a description of book details, The logged user can only write one review about that book, so if the user didn't make a review the "review.html" template shows him the information about the book plus a form for him to enter his review and rating, and if already submitted his review, it shows him the information plus his review in a bootstrap list form. when I submit the review, nothing happens, the URL stays the same, but the information I submitted gets added to it, and the "success.html" template as entended.

> Application.py

```
@app.route("/books/<int:book_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def review(book_id):
    ''' Prints to user Full information about a book + API information + prompts for user's review. '''

    # Get book information from books table using book_id got from books.html
    bookInfo = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id=:book_id", {"book_id": book_id}).fetchone()

    # Error handling.
    if bookInfo is None:
        raise RuntimeError("Error @ route: review, didn't fetch book information from books table.")

    # Need ISBN from books template.
    res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "RXTP9fIaG5qVUetlVTHgQ", "isbns": f"{bookInfo['isbn']}"})

    if res is None:
        raise RuntimeError("Error @ route: reveiw, Error in goodReads API.")

    # Convert API response to JSON format.
    bookInfo2 = res.json()

    # GoodReads API values.
    averageRating = bookInfo2["books"][0]["average_rating"]
    ratingsCount = bookInfo2["books"][0]["ratings_count"]

    # Check if the user made a review
    haveReview = db.execute("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE user_id=:user_id", {"user_id": session["user_id"]}).fetchone()

    if haveReview is None:

        if request.method == "POST":

            # User review and rating.
            review = request.form["review"]
            rating = int(request.form["rating"])

            if db.execute("INSERT INTO reviews (user_id, book_id, review_text, review_rating)\
                           values (:user_id, :book_id, :review_text, :review_rating)",\
                           {"user_id": 1, "book_id": book_id, "review_text": review,\
                           "review_rating": int(rating)}) is None:

                           raise RuntimeError("Error @ route review, didn't insert into reviews table.")
            else:
                db.commit()
                return render_template("success.html")

        return render_template("review.html",bookInfo=bookInfo,averageRating=averageRating,ratingsCount=ratingsCount,\
                               makeReview="0")



    return render_template("review.html",bookInfo=bookInfo,averageRating=averageRating,ratingsCount=ratingsCount, \
                          haveReview=haveReview,makeReview="1")
```

> review.html

```
{%extends "base.html"%}

{%block title%}Review{%endblock%}
 <!-- {%block var2%}{{url_for('register')}}{%endblock%} -->


{%block body%}

<!-- Book details, and user's review -->
<div class="container">
<dl class="row">
<dt class="col-sm-3">Book title</dt>
<dd class="col-sm-9">{{bookInfo.title}}</dd>

<dt class="col-sm-3">Book author</dt>
<dd class="col-sm-9">{{bookInfo.author_name}}</dd>

<dt class="col-sm-3">ISBN</dt>
<dd class="col-sm-9">{{bookInfo.isbn}}</dd>

<dt class="col-sm-3">Publication year</dt>
<dd class="col-sm-9">{{bookInfo.publish_year}}</dd>

<dt class="col-sm-3">GoodReads average Rating</dt>
<dd class="col-sm-9">{{averageRating}}</dd>

<dt class="col-sm-3">Goodreads number of ratings</dt>
<dd class="col-sm-9">{{ratingsCount}}</dd>
</div>

{%if makeReview == '1'%}
<div class="container">
  <dl class='row'>
  <dt class="col-sm-3">Your rating</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">{{haveReview.review_rating}} </dd>

 <dt class="col-sm-3">Your review</dt>
 <dd class="col-sm-9"> {{haveReview.review_text}}</dd>
</div>

{%elif makeReview == '0'%}
  <form class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="review">Your Review</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="review" name="review" placeholder="Submit a review." rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="rating">Your rating</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="rating" name="rating" placeholder="Submit a rating.">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
{%endif%}

{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify `method="post"` for your post:

```
 <form class="container" method="post">
```

Because the [default method for forms is `GET`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method) And if that is the case `request.method == "POST"` won't be `True`...