# search button in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I made the search successful, but I have a problem, how when the submit and input button is empty, the data does not appear

model

```
public function db_tracking($cari){
    $data = $this->db->query("SELECT id_service,kd_cs,tracking_number,nama_cs,reciver_name,tanggal,status,tgl_pickup,jam_pickup,nama_kecamatan AS tujuan, nama_kabupaten AS asal FROM service s
        INNER JOIN customers c ON s.id_cs=c.id_cs 
        INNER JOIN kabupaten k ON s.id_origin=k.id_kab 
        INNER JOIN kecamatan p ON p.id_kec=s.id_destination WHERE tracking_number LIKE '%$cari%' ORDER BY id_service DESC ");
    return $data->result();
}
```

Controller

```
public function hasil_cari(){
  $cari=$this->input->post('submit');
  $data['tracking'] = $this->M_home->db_tracking($cari);
  $this->load->view('frontend/v_hasil_cari', $data);
}
```

view

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('home/hasil_cari')?>" action="GET">
      <div class="tracking"> 
           <textarea type="text"  name="submit" placeholder="Track Your Number" class="track"></textarea> 
      </div> 
     <div class="tracking-btn">
       <button type="submit">Track Shipment</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you change the name attribute of your textarea from *submit* to something else?
```<textarea type="text"  name="track" placeholder="Track Your Number" class="track"></textarea>```

Then you can get the value in your controller like so:
```$cari=$this->input->post('track');```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is not using post method, but it's using get (btw you've a typo on it, it should be `method="GET"`, but nevertheless default form method is still a [GET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2314441/8566549) not a POST), change the `submit` to `get` should solve the empty `submit` value :

```
$cari=$this->input->get('submit');
```

---

**Edit**

---

If you want to show all search results when the submit textarea is empty, you could make a conditional query like this :

```php
public function db_tracking($cari){
    $query = "SELECT id_service,kd_cs,tracking_number,nama_cs,reciver_name,tanggal,status,tgl_pickup,jam_pickup,nama_kecamatan AS tujuan, nama_kabupaten AS asal FROM service s
        INNER JOIN customers c ON s.id_cs=c.id_cs 
        INNER JOIN kabupaten k ON s.id_origin=k.id_kab 
        INNER JOIN kecamatan p ON p.id_kec=s.id_destination ";
    $query .= !empty($cari) ? "WHERE tracking_number LIKE '%$cari%' " : '';
    $query .= "ORDER BY id_service DESC ";
    $data = $this->db->query($query);
    return $data->result();
}
```