# can a form without a method attribute work properly?

Tags: html, forms

I came across a HTML code where a form is submitted without any method attribute, so I want to know in this case which method is used?

Comment: See other questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method). To sum up: yes, it's valid and GET is assumed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the default form HTTP method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp shows that it is GET (which surprised me a bit!)