# How can i connect React frontend to flask backend

Tags: reactjs, http, flask, python-requests, axios

I havea form in the React front end as follows :

```
export function Services() {
    return (
    <div>
        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/">
            <label for="stock">stock</label>
            <input type="text" id="stock" name="stock" />
            </form>
      
            <h2>Services </h2>
    </div>
    );
}
```

I need to send the data to my flask app at the given port. The code there is :

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        stock = request.form('stock')
        return stock
    else:
        return "Post request was not made"
```

Everytime i run this, it says post request was not made.
What mistake am i doing and how should i proceed to connect the react frontend to flask backend.

Answer (score 0):

The [default method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method) for the `<form>` tag is `GET`. To change it to `POST`:

```js
export function Services() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/" method="post">
        <!-- ... -->
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```