# POST content is empty at reception

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I have a string that I would like to pass from JS to PHP via a hidden input, but the POST form does not return anything at arrival (I checked it with a `var_dump($_POST)`), which never happened to me at all.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form action='' id='hash-form'>
    <input type='hidden' id='hash' name='hash'/>
</form>
```

Here is my JS code for changing the value and submitting:

```
document.getElementById("hash").value = content;
console.log(document.getElementById("hash").value);
document.getElementById("hash-form").submit();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The HTML code you have posted does not include the `submit` button that your JavaScript clicks. Thus, your hidden input isn't part of the firm that is submitted.

Comment: Oh yeah, it was set to submit() before I desperately did all the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form lacks of the `method` attribute, thus it's GET by default, not post.

Add `method="POST"` into a `form` tag.

[What is the default form HTTP method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314401/what-is-the-default-form-http-method)

Comment: Thanks, you were indeed right, I can't believe I forgot this!