# I cannot $_post value into a <form></form> in chrome but works in IE

Tags: php

I cannot `$_post['value_to_be_posted']` value into a `<form><input type="hidden" value="<? echo  $_post['value_to_be_posted'] ?>"></form>` in chrome but works in IE and ff.

Any ideas

Thanks
Jean

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot ? What's in the source code ?

Comment: Yeah, please clarify your question by showing more code and especially describing what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: dear people,
the form is simple html, not much to the code error. 
if it were a code error it would not work in ff, and chrome.

Comment: Jean, then please describe in more detail what doesn't work. Is the variable written into the source code at all?

Comment: I have this form
<form action="" method="post">

<input type="text" name="one" />
</form>

and want the value of the above form when submitted to be the input of the hidden field in another form

<form action="" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="test" value="$_POST['one']"/>
</form>


thats it

Comment: *sigh* I understand that. But *what exactly is not working*? Is the variable not being transmitted, or is it not being printed into the source code at all?

Comment: Please show use the exact code you use to generate the output, and also the generated output. Copypaste will work best. Add it to the end of your question, and format it as code, so it's readable. Thank you.

Comment: @pekka the variable is not transmitted and its not being printed into the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP won't care what browser is receiving the HTML it's generating. It'll spit out the same data for Chrome as it would for IE and FF. Most likely your POST value has one or more characters in it that are "breaking" the HTML of the page, and IE/FF are being a bit more forgiving than Chrome is. Try this:

```
<form action=... method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="fieldname" value="<?php htmlspecialchars($_POST['one']) ?>" />
</form>
```

Passing the insertable data through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) will escape any HTML metacharacters, (the quote characters, the angle brackets, and ampersand: ' " < > &), and this will keep the inserted data from 'taking over' your form if any of those characters are present.

Answer (score 0):

First: PHP is case sensitive, so it should be `$_POST`. Second: pay attention to the quotes - if your posted value has a `"` inside it, you'll have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of varying default `method` values for `<form>` elements. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225735/ie7-default-form-method-is-get-how-can-i-tell-if-its-user-entered-or-default)

Try using a specific `<form method='POST'>` and see whether it works better.

Comment: @Jean then why don't you say so in your question? This is why quoting the original HTML is a good thing.

Comment: I have this form <form action="" method="post"> <input type="text" name="one" /> </form> and want the value of the above form when submitted to be the input of the hidden field in another form <form action="" method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="test" value="$_POST['one']"/> </form>