# PHP or Browser Security Hack concern and weird behavior

Tags: php, security, post, get

I have noticed during a transfer from a development server to production a potential browser security concern.

In a PHP file, I have a simple login form, `POST`ing to itself.  The basic HTML looks like:

```
<form action="http://mysite.com/includes/login/login.php" method="post">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
                Username:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="username" size="15" maxlength="64"  tabindex=1 />
            </td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Password:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="pword" size="15" maxlength="40" tabindex=2 />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"  tabindex=3 /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
</form>​​​​​​​
```

I noticed when I eliminated (by accident) the ending quote from the form action (e.g., `<form action="http://mysite.com/includes/login/login.php method="post">`) the form redirected to a "page not found" as it should.  But it also appended the `$_POST` data as `$_GET` data.  So the browser displayed the login information as:

```
http://mysite.com/includes/login/login.php%20method=?username=theperson&pword=happyday&submit=Login&submitted=TRUE
```

I get the same response in IE and Chrome.  Is this a big security hole or not?  I know I can view similar information in the developer tools, but I am wondering if a hacker could use this and if there is anything I should do to protect it.  Also, can anyone explain why the `$_POST` data was converted to `$_GET` data?

Comment: Well, a 'hacker' does not crack things. Apart from that: who is able to see the log files on your server?

Comment: Your form is converting to get as technically there is no method and apparently the default is GET - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2225873/1791606.

Comment: no there is no security concern, default method is get ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form looks like this:

```
<form action="http://mysite.com/includes/login/login.php method="post">
```

it’s equivalent to this:

```
<form action="http://mysite.com/includes/login/login.php method=" post">
```

which [will result](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tokenization.html#attribute-name-state) in a form with two attributes:

- `action`: `http://mysite.com/includes/login/login.php method=`
- `post"`: *empty*

Since there is no method attribute specified, the method GET is implied.

The only security consideration here is that sensitive data is sent via URL which can later show up in proxy and server logs, apart from the fact that you’re sending the login credentials over a non-secure channel.

Comment: That was what I was looking for... where the fingerprint of this could be dangerous.  Good summary as well!

Answer (score 3):

Only one answer here, it was converted probably because by missing the last `"` it made the `<form>` element invalid, so the browser defaulted to a GET request.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no. You have nothing to worry about.

Long answer?

The hole you're talking about is a code error on the website itself correct? If that's the case it is only a security hole **if you leave the bug in the code**.

A hacker will not be able to modify the html code on the website to create this glitch. The only thing they would be able to do is download the html code, create a new html document and modify that. In that case, the html with the bug would only be on their computer and not on the production site meaning other users are uneffected.

If a hacker is capable of modifying files *on the web server* then your security hole is elsewhere and outside the scope of this question.

Comment: "A hacker will not be able to modify the html code on the website to create this glitch." - This is not entirely true: Once a page is served the DOM can be manipulated (no need to create a new file). I could modify the form and leave the login page open on a shared computer (with https confirmation, etc) and have it send data via GET or to another server entirely. It's low risk (and almost every site is "vulnerable" to this), and I'm sure you know all this, but be careful how you phrase it - you don't want someone relying on, for instance, hidden inputs thinking that they can't be modified.

Comment: I agree that they shouldn't be able to access the web server; that would be the ultimate in security holes.  I was just startled to see the password staring right back at me.  @Qoop gave a very good link in the response above; it explains why the default is `$_GET`.  Given the choices, I am not sure why $_GET became the default... maybe alphabetical order  ;)

Comment: Good point Ben, I should maybe say that the effect is only present on the computer the hacker is using. If its a public terminal then any user should be wary. But again, this has very little to do with the site's security and more to do with the actual design of the web/browsers.