# Jsp post with jquery to servlet

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am using a jsp to send a form to a servlet. At the server side the processing is done and then I want to present an alert to the user informing him whether it was successful or not. The thing is that I get no alert but no exception as well. And when the post ends I see (though I don't want to) the values of the form on the browser url like a get.... Here is the code

```
<form id="register" class="form-signin" >
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register here</h2>
First Name:<input type="text" name="firstName" class="input-block-level" placeholder="user name" required><br>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastName" class="input-block-level" placeholder="user name" required><br>
User Name:<input type="text" name="user" class="input-block-level" placeholder="user name" required><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" required><br>
Retype Password:<input type="password" name="retypedPassword" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" required><br>
Email:<input type="email" name="email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="email required"><br>
Retype Email:<input type="email" name="retypedEmail" class="input-block-level" placeholder="email required"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitButton").on("click", function(){

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "RegisterServlet", //process to mail
            data: $("#register").serialize(),
            success: function(msg){

                alert(msg);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure editing account. User name already taken");
            }
        });

});

});

</script>
```

on the server side

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String username = request.getParameter("user");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String retypedPassword = request.getParameter("retypedPassword");
    String email =request.getParameter("email");
    String retypedEmail = request.getParameter("retypedEmail");
    String hash = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    if(firstName == null || firstName.equals("")){
        errorMsg = "First name can't be null or empty.";
    }
    if(lastName == null || lastName.equals("")){
        errorMsg = "Last name can't be null or empty.";
    }
    if(username == null || username.equals("")){
        errorMsg = "User name can't be null or empty.";
    }
    if(password == null || password.equals("")){
        errorMsg = "Password can't be null or empty.";
    }
    if(retypedPassword == null || retypedPassword.equals("")){
        errorMsg = "Retype password can't be null or empty.";
    }
    if(email == null || email.equals("")){
        errorMsg = "Email can't be null or empty.";
    }
    if(retypedEmail == null || retypedEmail.equals("")){
        errorMsg = "Retyped email can't be null or empty.";
    }
    if(password.equals(retypedPassword)==false){
        errorMsg = "Passwords do not match.";
    }
    if(retypedEmail.equals(email)==false){
        errorMsg = " Emails are not the same.";
    }
    if(errorMsg != null){
        response.setContentType("text/plain");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
        response.getWriter().write(errorMsg);  

    }
```

but i get nothing even if i try to. What is wrong with this code? Why After submiting I see the params on the url??

Comment: try adding logs on the client & the server side. Debug the flow. You will get to know where is it breaking.

Comment: You should prevent default behavior of form submit. For example, by adding `return false;` at the end of `click` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why After submiting I see the params on the url??

You can see these params in URL because your form is not submitting using ajax (jquery) you have to use `submit` handler on form, instead of click handler on button.

When you are binding click event on `submit` button, before reaching on jquery its submitting your form.

Use this: `e.preventDefault();` for preventing default submission of form.

Instead of using `submit` button click handler:

```
$("#submitButton").on("click", function(){
  //your code
}
```

Use `form` submit handler:

```
$('#register').on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();//preventing default submission 
  //your code
}
```

Comment: @Regent as i can see in OP's code. I believe his form is submitting by default jquery ajax call is not working.

Comment: Default request is sent in original code, yes. But the most important part in your answer is `e.preventDefault();` (which was not there in the beginning), not _change button click to form submit_.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, problem has been solved. It appears that the return false, or e.preventDefault() fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... your answer helped me... can you please clarify few things, if data need to be passed to servlet then we need to use `submit` instead of `click`.. can you please explain a bit more on this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your form is being submitted via the ´´ control in place of your javascript.  The default method of a form is GET (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2225873/1063929) for a great explanation) and that's why you're seeing the parameters in the address bar.

Change the input type from `submit` to `button`, or replace the `<input>` with a `<button>` and you'll have much tighter control over what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is your register form get submitted and your ajax call fails.

> I see (though I don't want to) the values of the form on the browser
>   url like a get

Since form gets submitted and method is not specified it is by default get which leads to parameters being sent via url.

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#register").on("submit", function(){
    /* to do here */
    return false;// restricts form submit
  }
};
```